# Map caps to esc for RHEL 5?

Tags: vim, rhel, x11, keyboard

I have an older version of RHEL. In newer versions, there is usually an option to map the caps key to the esc key. How would I do this in an old version?

Going to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout Options -> CapsLock Key behavior doesn't have the option to switch caps lock key to escape key.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
clear Lock
```

See [Remapping Caps Lock with xmodmap doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36282/remapping-caps-lock-with-xmodmap-doesnt-work) for explanations.

Run `xmodmap - <~/.Xmodmap` to apply your changes immediately. They will be applied automatically when you log in in the future.

(By the way, this is *essentially* what's going on under the hood in RHEL 6, which is apparently where you got the desire for this feature in RHEL 5. This is what I meant by my deleted comment that this stuff had been nailed down years before. All they've done is put a little GUI glaze on top of an ancient mechanism.)

Comment: You also need to remove the `Lock` modifier. And there's no need to restart the X session.

Comment: I considered adding the `xmodmap(1)` stuff, but didn't feel the need to complicate things. The setting needs to be persistent eventually, and it's not like you're going to be changing it that often.