# Swap CapsLock and Control using xmodmap (man page solution does not work)

Tags: xmodmap

I have just upgraded from Fedora 14 with Gnome desktop to Fedora 20 with
Mate desktop.  Under F14, I previously swapped CapsLock with Control_Left,
and Alt_Right with Control_Right.  These I did by adding the following lines
to /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common  (excuse the 'xmodmap's on each line)

```
xmodmap -e 'clear lock'
xmodmap -e 'clear control'
xmodmap -e 'remove mod1 = Alt_R'
xmodmap -e 'add control = Caps_Lock Alt_R'
xmodmap -e 'add mod1 = Control_R'
xmodmap -e 'add lock = Control_L'
```

Under F14, they work as expected.  However, when I copy these to
/etc/X11/xinitrc-common under F20, the CapsLock Control_L swap does not
happen.  Instead, both keys become CapsLock.  The Alt_R/Control_R swap does
work correctly.

Next, I tried the solution offered in the xmodmap man page, and also here:
[Remapping Caps Lock with xmodmap doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36282/remapping-caps-lock-with-xmodmap-doesnt-work)

```
xmodmap -e 'remove Lock = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'remove Control = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'add Lock = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_L'
```

Strangely, CapsLock and Control_L keys are now both Control_L.

Doing all swaps with keycode mappings works like a charm though:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
xmodmap -e 'clear Control'
xmodmap -e 'remove Mod1 = Alt_R'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Control_L'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 37 = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 108 = Control_R'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = Alt_R'
xmodmap -e 'add Lock = Caps_Lock'
xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_L Control_R'
xmodmap -e 'add Mod1 = Alt_R'
```

The original keycodes before the swap are 66=CapsLock, 37=Control_L, 108=Alt_R,
105=Control_R.

I would like to understand why the first two methods would not work.  Any
ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to switch the right control key and the menu key on a laptop (Dell swapped their physical position on the keyboard).

For some reason, the modifier keys have to have two things in place to work.  It needs to know that a particular key is Control_R, and it needs to know that the particular key has the Control modifier attached to it.

So I had to swap the keycodes, and then separately remove control function from one key and add it to another.  I only needed to do the first step when I experimented with swapping letter keys.

My guess is that the modifier functions are just handled differently by the system.